# I need an unzip command line tool for Windows, that supports redistribution

Tags: windows, command-line, zip

I'm building a small client app that downloads a specific .zip file form a website and needs to unzip the file. it would be easiest for me if i could have a command line unzip utility that supports WinXP, Win Vista, and Win7, and allows me to redistribute the utility with my app.

what unzip utilities meet my needs?

i'm a 7zip user, but i don't understand the LGPL license that it's released under, so i'm hoping someone else can fill me in and give me some suggestions / guidance.

Comment: Definitely 7-zip.  Just note that you have to offer your customers a copy of the 7-zip source code (not the code for your app) and *you have to be able to give them this source code even if 7-zip otherwise disappears off the face of the earth* so make a copy of it now.

Answer (score 5):

I don't speak legalese either, but I think you *can* redistribute 7zip with your program.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License):

> The main difference between the GPL and the LGPL is that the latter can be linked to (in the case of a library, 'used by') a non-(L)GPLed program, regardless of whether it is free software or proprietary software. This non-(L)GPLed program can then be distributed under any chosen terms if it is not a derivative work.

There also is [InfoZip](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html), released under [InfoZip License](http://www.info-zip.org/license.html).